# Spring GetMapping annotation exception

Tags: java, spring

There is the following method from the controller class:

```
    @GetMapping("{id:" + REGEXP + "}")
    @ResponseBody
    public SomeObject getById(@PathVariable UUID id) {
        return someObjectService.getById(id));
    }
```

REGEXP is a simple regular expression string. In someObjectService getById method handles the case when object cannot be found by id and throws exception. There is also exception handler class for such cases to customize error response:

```
    @ExceptionHandler({ResourceNotFoundException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ResponseBody
    public CustomErrorResponse handleNotFoundCase (ResourceNotFoundException exception) {
        CustomErrorResponse customerErrorResponse = new CustomErrorResponse();
        // filling CustomErrorResponse with specific data using 'exception'
        return customerErrorResponse;
    }
```

So, when I test `getById` with some non-existing id, which passes REGEXP check, expected result = achieved result: 404 and json body of the error has the structure of `CustomErrorResponse` (from the handler).

However, when I do the same with id, which does NOT pass REGEXP check - 404 occurres, BUT json body of the error is default (bootstrap), it has not `CustomErrorResponse` structure.

The question is: what kind of exception could be thrown and where (for its further appropriate handling) when id in `@GetMapping("{id:" + REGEXP + "}")` does not pass the regexp check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create regex to check if uuid is proper that this is not necessary and

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public SomeObject getById(@PathVariable UUID id) {
```

will validate that.

On the other hand if you have more strict requirement on that than you need to use Pattern validator:

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class Ctrl {
    // ...
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String getById(@Pattern(regexp = REGEXP) @PathVariable String id) {
        return someObjectService.getById(UUID.fromString(id)));
    }

}
```

Note, that Pattern validator do not work on UUID type, so you have to convert String to UUID manually.

You can read more about validation in https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Answer (score 1):

Why do you try to post json in your get mapping? 
In this case you'll need to use localhost:8080/yourApp/entity/{id:10} 
Is that actually what you need instead of localhost:8080/yourApp/entity/10?

Please have a look at this page about how REST Endpoints should be designed: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design

Regarding your question - you can't use validation in such case. You need to add your custom validator for this field
Please find section "Custom Validator" here:
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-validation-example/